# Flutter - raise widget above other widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How can I raise widget above other widgets,
I need to show background opacity when focus on input and show the input above ask widget
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm interesting question. Not sure if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852314/how-can-i-create-a-widget-with-a-semi-transparent-background-and-an-opaque-foreg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612599/make-boxdecoration-image-faded-transparent

Comment: Not really, he ask for background all over the screen and I need to show only one widget above all and the rest will get background with Positioned.fill or something

Comment: try wrapping the widget in `Material` widget; set color to transparent and change elevation as required.

Comment: I tried but the children not changing the elevation

Comment: Great I'll wait. thank you :)

Comment: this package might help https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sample code as an example

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[X(), X(), X(), X()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class X extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _XState createState() => _XState();
}

class _XState extends State<X> {
  bool isElevated = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('_XState.build() tap');
        setState(() {
          isElevated = !isElevated;
        });
      },
      child: Material(
        elevation: isElevated ? 40 : 0, //change as needed
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), //change as needed
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but still can't put background on those who with elevation 0 :(

Comment: the example was meant to show the use of elevation; the effect you want to achieve will require some color backdrop logic.

Comment: and you can change the background color if you like. and many more properties.

Comment: That's the main problem,
You need to set Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4) background on all over the page and show above the background only the elevations items, and the others (elevation 0) need to be behind the background.

Answer (score 0):

You may try stack as a parent widget of all other widgets.

Comment: Please provide more information/examples to your answer